# Capitalization of honorifics such as "your excellency", "your majesty", "your holiness"

Tags: orthography, capitalization, honorifics

When addressing an ambassador, is it

> I agree with your excellency.

or should *your, excellency*, or both be capitalized?

Likewise with "your majesty" and "your holiness".

Comment: One capitalizes both of those, Your Majesty.

Answer (score 2):

All those should be capitalised as they refer to specific dignitaries. In the same way you capitalise Q for Queen if you are speaking about a specific person, past or present e.g. Queen Anne, Queen Elizabeth ll etc.

If you are just writing about any king, or an ambassador you would not capitalise any of it.

e.g. 'At a service for commemoration for a late king, one would expect many excellencies to be in attendance'.